# Indefinite Integral of a Function Represented as a Power Series

Tags: calculus, power-series

I have the function $f(x)=\int\frac{1}{8+x^3}dx$ and I am trying to represent it as a power series and I have gotten to this point
\begin{align}
f(x) &= \int\frac{1}{8+x^3}dx \\
\frac{d}{dx}[f(x)] &= \frac{1}{8+x^3} \\
&= \frac{1}{8}*\frac{1}{1-(-\frac{x^3}{8})} \\
&= \frac{1}{8}*\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(-\frac{x^3}{8}\right)^n \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{x^{3n}}{8^{n+1}} \\
\int\frac{d}{dx}[f(x)]dx &= \int\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{x^{3n}}{8^{n+1}}dx \\
f(x)&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left[\int(-1)^n\frac{x^{3n}}{8^{n+1}} dx \right] \\
&= C + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{x^{3n+1}}{8^{n+1}(3n+1)}
\end{align}

I am having trouble finding the constant ($C$), below is my work to find the constant,

\begin{align}
\int\frac{1}{8+x^3}dx&=\left. C + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{x^{3n+1}}{8^{n+1}(3n+1)}\right\vert_{x=0} \\
\int\frac{1}{8}dx &= C \\
\frac{x}{8}+C_2 &= C_1
\end{align}

This is where I am stuck, I cannot figure out how to solve for the constant of the power function. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: $C$ is an arbitrary constant as with any indefinite integral.  You can't "solve" for it.  Your work appears to be correct, and the expression just before the sentence that starts with "I am having trouble" is the answer.

Comment: I have to find the interval of convergence for the power series, so do I just ignore $C$ and find the interval of convergence of the series?

Comment: $C$ won't affect the interval of convergence at all.

Comment: Alrighty, thank you very much!